Why this call to DSolve gives this error in V 14.1?
Also reported to Wolfram support just in case.  [CASE:5167904].

Is there a way to correct this error from the new version of Mathematica 14.1? I do not know what changed and what is wrong:
ode = y'[x] == Cos[x] - (Sin[x] - y[x]) *y[x];
DSolve[ode, y[x], x, IncludeSingularSolutions -> True]


I am using the new V 14.1 on windows 10 home edition.
Anyone else can duplicate this on other systems?
Just in case this is a bug, I also send email to Wolfram support as I am not sure what is going on.
Update
Here is another one:
ode=y'[x]==1+a*(x-y[x])*y[x]
DSolve[ode,y[x],x,IncludeSingularSolutions->True]


The strange thing is that DSolve keeps running and gives solution. But I am now not sure to trust the solution or not due to this message.
Update
Here is another one
ode = D[y[x], x] == y[x]/x - Tan[y[x]/x]
DSolve[ode, y[x], x, IncludeSingularSolutions -> True]


Update
Here is another one.
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ode = (x*Sin[y[x]/x] - y[x]*Cos[y[x]/x]) + (x*Cos[y[x]/x])*D[y[x], x] == 0
DSolve[ode, y[x], x, IncludeSingularSolutions -> True]



First, it pretty much has to be a bug, right? There's nothing wrong with your syntax.   It looks like they forgot to check the result of Solve (similar to x0 = x /. Solve[x == x + 1, x][[1]]).

@MichaelE2 Yes, I agree it has to be a bug. But strange thing DSolve still works and gives solution.

Just because one sub-case equation being solved does not have a solution, does not mean any other solutions will be reject. For all I know, it meant that one solution strategy was rejected and DSolve moved on to try another. -- Do you know if any solutions are missing?

@MichaelE2 both ode'a above are Riccati odes. Riccati ode have no singular solutions.  Mathematica gives singular solution in the second example I posted $y=x$. As far as general solution(s), Mathematica gave 3 for the first example. I just checked with Maple, it only gave one general solution for both example.  So No, Mathematica is not missing any solution, if anything, it is giving more solutions !

You may be aware that IncludeSingularSolutions includes two kinds of solutions, the usual singular solutions and solutions that are limits of the general solution (as the constant parameters approach some value). The $y=x$ solution to the 2nd ODE comes from a limit. In terms of the general solution returned, it is the limit as C[1] -> 0. However, it actually comes (as I believe from Trace[]) from the limit at infinity of another form of the general solution, which seems odd to me. But I did not pursue it.

@MichaelE2  yes, I knew that, Mathematica has its definition of what singular solutions(s) are. Help calls these "equilibrium". From help: The singular solutions in this case are the "equilibrium" solutions y=0 and y=1:  but all other text books mean by singular solution as the envelope of the family of solutions. This is the standard definition. But it does not hurt ofcourse to generate these extra ones by Mathematica.  Extra information is OK.

Note also that the 3rd solution to the 1st ODE has a divergent integral. One can set the initial point for the integration with either hack found here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/305829/4999

Long comment: It's a weird-looking bug.  DSolve[] makes these two calls to a solver, which look the same to me, aside from variable names:
DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`FirstOrderODE[
 Derivative[1][y][x] -> Cos[x] - Sin[x] y[x] + y[x]^2, C[1]]

DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`FirstOrderODE[
 Derivative[1][DSolve`DSolveExtendedLibraryDump`z][
   DSolve`DSolveExtendedLibraryDump`t] -> 
  Cos[DSolve`DSolveExtendedLibraryDump`t] - 
   Sin[DSolve`DSolveExtendedLibraryDump`t] 
 DSolve`DSolveExtendedLibraryDump`z[DSolve`DSolveExtendedLibraryDump`t] + 
   DSolve`DSolveExtendedLibraryDump`z[
    DSolve`DSolveExtendedLibraryDump`t]^2, C[1]]

The first yields an answer. The second yields the errors and results in $Failed.
The first code may be obtained from the second by the following replacements:
{DSolve`DSolveExtendedLibraryDump`t -> x, 
 DSolve`DSolveExtendedLibraryDump`z -> y}

Why don't they yield equivalent results? My first guess is some sort of assignment is leaking.

It looks the same for the new (2nd) problem, too.

aside from variable names  do you think I should add tag "letter_makes_difference" in this case to my question?   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letter-makes-difference

@Nasser Not sure. It's an internal letter that makes a difference, not something a user would or should do. Nor can the user control this. That is, under normal usage, no letter makes a difference.
